# react-native + Android 4 problems

Tags: android, react-native, adb, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I'm trying to build a react-native app for Android 4.1.2

I compile the app OK, and then get a red screen with the "could not get native call queue" message.

In propopsed solutions : use adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 gets "closed port error" twice. Since adb reverse works only in Android 5 how can I do making this working properly ?

Other question : is it possible to unplugged phone and leave the server debug wifi coverage to test the app in the street ?
(I guess in Cordova we could)

Thanks for replies.

Comment: I have similar error `Couldn't get the native call queue: bridge configuration isn't available. this probably indicates there was an issue loading the JS bundle, e.g. it wasn't packaged into the app or was malformed. Check your logs ('adb logcat') for more information.` -- I ran `adb logcat` from command line, can't make out heads or tails. I had the app loading, but I ran `watchman start` or `npm start` (can't recall which) on command line and it broke it. Gonna try shut emulator and terminals down and start again with same RN project.

Comment: Restart emulator and RN on terminal, still get this error.

Comment: try this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi 

same wifi is worked in android 4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Create dir: `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. Create file `index.android.js` which is a clone of index.js: `cp index.js index.android.js`
3. `react-native link`
4. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
5. `react-native run-android`